# How to overlay bitmap over another bitmap at particular XY position

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am working on a project where I have used canvas and user can touch move one bitmap overlay to another bitmap. When user presses save button then both bitmaps should merge and become a single bitmap. I have done all things and now merging two bitmap at XY position remains. During my research I found following code.

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

But this code overlay bitmap at (0,0) location. I want to overlay bitmap at my given location. Please suggest some solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below code

```
private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, x,y, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Where x and y are actual positions where you have to draw the overlay bitmap.

Comment: Yes it is pixel value.