# Android Overlaying Bitmap over another Bitmap Issue

Tags: java, android, android-activity, mobile, bitmap

I am working on the Android app for the Eyewer Team and I am trying to overlay a Bitmap over another Bitmap before uploading it to my database. I followed many stackoverflow questions and landed on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431026/how-to-overlay-bitmap-over-another-bitmap-at-particular-xy-position) one.

Looks legit but I am facing a bit a difficulty placing the overlay bitmap and its position.

This is where I want it to be placed:

[image: Bottom Left Corner]

**^ Bottom Left Corner**

Here's what I have right now:

```
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap_MainPic.getWidth(), Bitmap_MainPic.getHeight(), Bitmap_MainPic.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap_MainPic, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlay_logo, 50,50, null);
```

How can I position the overlay at the required position using my code or code of your suggestion?

Comment: how to position the drawn `Bitmap` (using `Canvas#drawBitmap` method)? is it what you are asking ?

Comment: I need to place the bitmap in the position displayed above. How do I get the coordinates of that position? (Bottom Left Corner) @pskink

Comment: See the link below:         
                                       
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431026/how-to-overlay-bitmap-over-another-bitmap-at-particular-xy-position/30431263#30431263