# How to add small bitmap in front of large bitmap image

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

we need to merge two images with background large image and in front of that a small bitmap and I am using this code then the result is like this what is wrong and how to solve this problem. here the image of the small image is not visible but in small image place a large image is placed
**

> Java code

**

```
  Bitmap backgroundimage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                        R.drawable.rec_);

                BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable= new BitmapDrawable( overlay(bitmap,backgroundimage));
                mBitmapDrawable.setGravity(CENTER);
                toolbar_layout.setBackground(mBitmapDrawable);





private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```

[image: img]

Comment: `canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);` what do you expect from this?

Comment: @pskink  Help me with the code for canvas to bitmap

Comment: and did you read `Canvas#drawBitmap()` methods official documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: @pskink  How to solve Bitmap() is not public issue?

Comment: what do you want `new Bitmap()` for? you have many `Bitmap#createBitmap` methods for it

Comment: why can't you just place one ImageView over another ImageView?

Comment: Will this code is useful? Try once
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431026/how-to-overlay-bitmap-over-another-bitmap-at-particular-xy-position/30431263#30431263